# How to count and plot with separated features?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Date     Visa  Mastercard  Amex  Paypal  
1/1/20   0     20          0     0       
2/1/20   15    0           0     0       
3/1/20   30    0           0     0       
4/1/20   0     15          0     0       
5/1/20   0     0           50    0
```

I will like to count the number of times Visa, mastercard, amex and paypal appeared, which is 2 times for visa and mastercard, 1x for amex and 0 for paypal. And then I will like to plot it.

Is there anyway to go about dealing with this? I do have a rough idea based on using `df.info()`

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

visa = df['Visa'].value_counts()
mc = df['Mastercard'].value_counts()
amex= df['Amex'].value_counts()
pp = df['Paypal'].value_counts()

plt.plot([visa,mc,amex,pp])
plt.show()
```

This takes the value counts and plots them all against each other.

Comment: Yep! If you want the number of occurrences greater than 0, use: `df[df > 0].value_counts` - that returns columns of the number of times that a row was greater than 0.